# IoT Hub Device-to-Coud preprocessing and Cloud-to-Device postprocessing

Tags: azure-iot-hub

My device uses a standard MQTT library (not the azure-device-sdk) to connect to my IoT hub. Unfortunately, it expects message payloads (device configurations, direct method invocations, etc.) to be represented in binary (which is contrary to IoT hubs Json-first approach) and to be encrypted and signed on the application layer. 
Is it somehow possible to "augment" the processing pipeline of an IoT hub with custom steps (e.g. register an Azure Function that is invoked before a message is sent to the device)? I've read about Microsoft's Azure IoT Protocol Gateway (https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-protocol-gateway) but it  seems kind of immature and not well-integratable with serverless architectures.

Comment: IoT Hub supports binary messages in both directions, JSON is not a requirement. The protocol gateway is used to connect devices using unsupported protocols (e.g. not MQTT, AMQP or HTTP).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The choice of encoding for the payload holds true for Device-to-Cloud and Cloud-to-Device messages, but unfortunately not for the Device Twin functionality of the IoT Hub, where the payload is alway encoded and transferred as Json.